# Как проверить наличие get параметра без значения

Tags: php, get

Есть к примеру ссылка site.ru/?get

Как мне узнать что параметр есть?

Comment: вы когда либо слышали про массивы `$_GET` ?

Comment: Да затупил))) Еще сам не мог понять почему isset ошибку выдаёт. Я в CI делал это и использовал $this->input->get('get') ))))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(isset($_GET[$value])){
//
}
```

Comment: спасибо))) Затупил чтот))